# syntax error, unexpected ':' on line 56

Tags: php, syntax-error

Been having some problems with this code, for some reason it works on one PHP script but this one refuses to work and I  have no Idea as to why, since I'm pretty new to PHP and learning POST and other stuff, this was working OK but I can't see what the problem is, since the PDO is the same as every other PHP file and they  work fine.

The error I've been getting :

> **syntax error**, unexpected ':' **on line 56** (AKA the :catid BindParam)

and my Code:

```
<?PHP
if (!defined('init_executes'))
{   
    header('HTTP/1.0 404 not found');
    exit;
}

$CORE->loggedInOrReturn();

//prepare multi errors
$ERRORS->NewInstance('forums_forum_forum');
//bind on success
$ERRORS->onSuccess('Forum Sucessfully Created..', '/index.php?page=forums');

$name1 = (isset($_POST['name']) ? $_POST['name'] : false);
$desc1 = (isset($_POST['desc']) ? $_POST['desc'] : false);
$catoid = (isset($_POST['catid']) ? $_POST['catid'] : false);
$rrtct1 = (isset($_POST['rrtct']) ? $_POST['rrtct'] : false);

if (!$name)
{
    $ERRORS->Add("Please enter a Forum title.");
}

if(!$catid)
{
    $ERRORS->Add("Please enter a Destination Catagory");
}

$ERRORS->Check('/index.php?page=forums');

####################################################################
## The actual script begins here

    //Determine the Position within the Category
    $res2 = $DB->prepare("SELECT `position` FROM `wcf_categories` WHERE id =:catids  ORDER BY `position` DESC LIMIT 1");
    $res2->bindParam(':catids', $catoid, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $res2->execute();

    if ($res2->rowCount() > 0)
    {
        $row2 = $res2->fetch();

        $position = $row2 + 1;

        unset($row2);

    }
    else
    {
        $position = 0;
    }
    unset($res2);

    $insert = $DB->prepare("INSERT INTO wcf_forums (category, name, description, position, required_rank_create_thread) VALUES (:catid, :name, :desc, :pos, :rank_thread);");
    $insert->bindParam(':catid', $catoid, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $insert->bindParam(':name', $name1, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $insert->bindParam(':desc', $desc1, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $insert->bindParam(':pos', $position, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $insert->bindParam(':rank_thread', $rrtct1, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $insert->execute();

    if ($insert->rowCount() < 1)
    {
        $ERRORS->Add("The website failed to insert the forum record.");
    }
    else
    {
        unset($insert);
        $ERRORS->triggerSuccess();
    }
    unset($insert);

####################################################################

$ERRORS->Check('/index.php?page=forums');

exit;
```

Comment: You just missed `single quote` in this statement `$res2->bindParam(':catids, $catoid, PDO::PARAM_INT);`

Comment: You are missing a closing single quote (`'`) in this line: `$res2->bindParam(':catids, $catoid, PDO::PARAM_INT);` *Edit:* Damn, too late :)

Comment: Why did you fix the code in your question? Did it fix the actual problem on your end?

Comment: Optimize - You changed the very line that was noted by hardik & Hexaholic- has this resolved the issue?

Comment: Hey - Yeah I noticed it once I looked at the code in the post, however it wasn't pointing to that line on the error, if it was it would haver been fixed before having to post, but thanks for the help! :)

Comment: Hey @Optimize: Please look on my answer. I'm pretty sure about it.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that you have problem in line `$insert->bindParam(':catid', $catoid, PDO::PARAM_INT);`

Try commenting this line and see if your error moves to the next one.

If it does, I think it should mean that there is problem with your ORM and table structure.

If error disappears, again check what changed in your db structure. There maybe something connected either to catid field in wcf_forums table, of the whole table structure. Also check your ORM configuration for that table.

Not sure that it will help to solve your problem, but that's what I'd do on your place.

Answer (score -1):

Try to change your query to:

`$insert = $DB->prepare('INSERT INTO wcf_forums (category, name, description, position, required_rank_create_thread) VALUES (:catid, :name, :desc, :pos, :rank_thread);');`

(quotes changed)

Comment: This will not make any difference.

Answer (score -1):

Remove semicolon `;` from this line before `)`

```
$insert = $DB->prepare("INSERT INTO wcf_forums (category, name, description, position, required_rank_create_thread) 
VALUES (:catid, :name, :desc, :pos, :rank_thread);");
                                                 ^
```

**Edited Code:**

```
$insert = $DB->prepare("INSERT INTO wcf_forums (category, name, description, position, required_rank_create_thread) VALUES (:catid, :name, :desc, :pos, :rank_thread)");
```

Comment: This is not the cause of the error the questioner is asking about. Also, terminating queries like this, while not necessary, would not cause problems.

Comment: No, it's because of this only that error coming @SverriM.Olsen. I'm pretty sure.

Comment: Wrong. The error they are getting is a *PHP syntax error*. It does not have anything to do with the SQL.